# True or False - Matrix Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$A^2 - AB - BA + B^2 = 0 \implies A = B $$

I know this is false but how can I go about proving it. I got to:

$$A^2 - AB - BA + B^2$$
$$ = (A - B)(A-B) = 0$$

I know that if A and B are matrices such that AB = 0 then AB need not be 0 but how can I show this equation wise without resorting to a counter examples which would a bit annoying in this case since it is matrix multiplication?

Comment: Once you get to $(A-B)(A-B)=0$, you should abstract away $A$ and $B$ and ask the more general question: is there a matrix $M\neq 0$ such that $M^2=0$? This is a much simpler question. Once you have $M$ you can easily find distinct $A$ and $B$ such that $A-B=M$, of course.

Comment: Thanks, I like this as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** False,choose $A$ to be zero matrix and $B$ such that $B^2=0$.For instance:

$ B=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Would there be a way of showing this without using a counter example?

Comment: I don't think so.For disproving something the best way is to give an example where the result does n't hold.The main idea is that given any $ n \in  \mathbb N $ you can always find a non zero matrix $A$ such that $ A^n=0 $,such matrices are called Nilpotent matrices.

Answer (score 6):

HINT:
$$A(A-B) -B(A-B)=0$$
$$(A-B)(A-B)=0$$

But from this does not follow that $A=B$, because $A-B$ is not necessary $0$.

Example:
$$M=
  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 1\\  
   0 & 0      
\end{array} } 
\right)
$$
$$M^2=0$$

Every two matrices $A, B$ such that $A-B=M$ give a counter example !

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: Your answer seems fine.(I din't downvote you)

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $det(A-B)\neq0$, then there exists inverse matrix of $A-B$. In the equation: $$(A-B)(A-B)=0$$
multiplicate by the $(A-B)^{-1}$, then we get:

$$A-B=0, $$
from there we get that the $A=B$, but it's impossible, because $det(A-B)\neq0$. So contradiction. Hence $det(A-B)=0$. So we don't necessary need A to be equal to B, just the determinant to be zero.

Answer (score 2):

The most general answer is that matrices do not form a [division algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algebra). A division algebra is basically an algebra in which multiplication has an inverse. There are only four division algebras: real numbers, complex numbers, quanternions and octonions. Square matrices are neither.

A specific consequence (as someone mentioned in an answer comment) is that there exist [nilpotent matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix), specifically nonzero square matrices $X$ for which $X^2=0$. So given an arbitrary square matrix $A$ and a degree-2 nilpotent matrix $X$ of the same order, you can make $B=A+X$ and thus, $(A-B)\cdot(A-B)=X^2=0$ even though $A- B=X\ne 0$ so $A\ne B$.